# Hint at how to find error in g4 file

Tags: antlr4

I have the following snippet of code (tried to paste in entire grammar but couldn't get submit to accept it for some reason:

```
fragment Y : 'y' | 'Y';
fragment Z : 'z' | 'Z';

fragment ATSIGN : '@' ;
```

which gives the following errors:

```
error(50): Sql.g4:101:21: syntax
error: unterminated rule (missing ';') detected at '';
[ This is the line fragment Z : 'z' | 'Z' ;]

fragment ATSIGN : ' @' while looking for rule element
error(50): Sql.g4:101:21: syntax
 error: missing COLON at '';\n\nfragment ATSIGN : '' while matching a lexer rule
```

I can't track back to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the name of your lexer rule between `fragment` and `:`. I assume you are trying to define `ATSIGN` here, such as the following:

```
fragment ATSIGN : '@';
```